# select column from files and write to new file with file name as column name

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have datasets formatted as follows:

```
    Theta   DeltaD  DeltaS  Lambda  Rho LogLik
1   0.0137060718    0.0378903969    0.4939959667    0.3795642767    0.57232859  -963.7743175455
2   0.0137060718    0.0378903969    0.4951036519    0.3795642767    0.57232859  -963.745770314
3   0.0136703063    0.038522257 0.4807565701    0.3551424944    0.5639182313    -964.5802838333
4   0.0136703063    0.0382752067    0.4597773216    0.3551424944    0.5621381788    -963.0634821126
5   0.0136703063    0.0377739624    0.4597773216    0.3486538546    0.5552092482    -963.315982188
6   0.0136119461    0.0359108581    0.4597773216    0.3486538546    0.5552092482    -963.5321138251
7   0.0136119461    0.0374395068    0.4597773216    0.3582883699    0.5862608093    -963.3432259866
8   0.0136119461    0.0374395068    0.4597773216    0.3582883699    0.5862608093    -963.3432259866
9   0.0136119461    0.0383243243    0.4597773216    0.3582883699    0.5862608093    -963.288725532
10  0.0136119461    0.0383243243    0.467850463 0.3582883699    0.5862608093    -963.058588502
```

I wanted to select column DeltaS from each file, and save the output as a csv or whatever delimited format but with file name as a column name.

I came up with a code as follows:

```
import glob
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import csv

outfile = open("final_DeltaS",'w')

list_of_files = []
for name in glob.glob('*iter.csv'):
    list_of_files.append(name)


def fileinput(files):
    for f in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        print f, df["DeltaS"]

fileinput(list_of_files)
```

But am stack on how to output the data from this loop :x
Expected output:

```
File_1  File_2
0.0378903969    0.4939959667
0.0378903969    0.4951036519
0.038522257 0.4807565701
0.0382752067    0.4597773216
0.0377739624    0.4597773216
0.0359108581    0.4597773216
0.0374395068    0.4597773216
0.0374395068    0.4597773216
0.0383243243    0.4597773216
0.0383243243    0.467850463
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work:

```
df_col_list = []
def fileinput(files):
    for f in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=['DeltaS'])
        df.rename(columns={'DeltaS':f}, inplace=True)
        df_col_list.append(df)

concat = pd.concat(df_col_list, axis = 1)
concat.to_csv(your_output_path)
```

You may need to strip the filename down to what you really want but this is trivial